# Concalc - "tcsetattr error: Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Tags: shell-script, pipe, command-substitution, error-handling, concalc

In a bash script I use the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

calc=$(concalc "$*")

printf "%s\n" "$calc"
```

I do get the result I want, but allways with this error message:
`tcsetattr error: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Does anyone know how to get rid of this? When I use `concalc` on its own it is no problem but as soon as I use it within a `command-substitution` or a `pipe` I get this message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to insist on setting some terminal attributes, like disabling echo, regardless of the mode it runs in (interactive or not). I assume it's somehow useful for scripts, since it doesn't do anything on the terminal between setting and resetting it otherwise.

Apart from fixing the code, you could just redirect the errors away:

```
calc=$(concalc "$*" 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: Yes, what `concalc` does with its standard output seems pointless, and the assumptions that it makes, wrong.  It's worth looking at tools such as `expr`, `dc`, and `bc` in these circumstances.

Comment: @JdeBP thanks for mentioning `expr` I did not know this. The only problem with `expr` as well as with `dc` and `bc` is that they do not support decimal values, so the only solution for this case in `bash` as far as I know is `awk`.

Comment: Who told you that `dc` and `bc` don't support decimal?  Was it someone who hadn't read about the scale factor setting?  (-:

Comment: `bc -l` supports decimals, plus some oddly named functions (trig, exp, log). e.g. `echo '1/7; s(3.14159265358979/2)' |bc -l` You can set the number of digits after the decimal point with `scale=123` in the program.

Comment: @ilkkachu; Thanks for the lesson! I finally found your commend (by chance though) ;-)